# Formula for Energy Of black body radiation

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

The formula for energy for blackbody radiation on some trusted websites is given by:

$$E_{\lambda}=\frac{8\pi hc}{\lambda^5\cdot\left(\exp\left(\dfrac{hc}{\lambda\cdot k\cdot t}\right)-1\right)}\tag1$$

Whereas, on some other trusted sites, it is given by:

$$E_{\lambda}=\frac{2\pi hc}{\lambda^5\cdot\left(\exp\left(\dfrac{hc}{\lambda\cdot k\cdot t}\right)-1\right)}\tag2$$

Please tell that which one is true, the formula with '8' in the numerator (formula 1) or '2' in the numerator (formula 2).

Comment: It should be $c^2$ in the numerator i.e. $$ E = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda k_B T} - 1} $$

Comment: Then multiplying by $4\pi/c$ gives the equation in terms of the [spectral energy form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Spectral_energy_density_form). That would give you $8\pi h c$ in the numerator.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRennie Your comment should probably be an answer instead.